# Как прописать зависимость vaadin компонентов в build.gradle

Tags: gradle, vaadin

Здравствуйте! С Gradle я не особо хорошо знаком, поэтому не знаю прописать зависимость vaadin компонентов. Я думаю, должно было получиться что-то вроде такого

```
compile("com.vaadin:ui");
```

Уверен что нужно указать версию vaadin, но не знаю как. 
Вообще я хочу ипортировать `com.vaadin.ui.TreeTable`

Что я делаю правильно а что нет?